# How to calculate overall area of multipy meshes that overlap itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have few meshes in Unity that are sometimes overlap / intersect.

These meshes are flat (z=0). It can be 3 situation like on picture below. Each time I want to calculate overall area (marked black color on the picture)

I think that it can be done based on calculate area taking only outer points of combined mesh? Does anyone can provide any example on idea how to do it?

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to calculate surface area of these meshes. What do you need more to explain?

Comment: I can confirm that Unity has no connection to anything like shape intersection calculations.  Note that "mesh" is really totally uninvolved here. You could *possibly* use a package like this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18544 but, confusingly, that does the 3D math of the sort of thing you're interested in.

Comment: The point is that I will never know how these objects will look like and how they will be intersect with each other etc.  On my example picture I was try to draw few possible situations and these objects are not on 45 degree on this picture (but they can look like this)

Answer (score 2):

I can point you to Weiler-Atherton clipping algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm) and a C++ implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99246/weiler-atherton-polygon-clipping-algorithm-in-c)

Another alternative (but more time consuming I think) method would be the following:

1. Triangulate your polygons (harder part) and mark them with the label of the original polygon
2. Compute the list of intersection between all triangles (much easier since you just have to intersect 2 triangles)
3. Compute the area of triangles intersected with different labels => the needed output

Comment: Indeed.  This question has nothing to do with meshes or Unity .. it's pure calculation.

Comment: Maybe it's pure calculation but my question was also is there any build in method in Unity for this.

Comment: @Tamas Ionut  Weiler-Atherton clipping algorithm is a good idea and for sure only one that I have in this moment. I will take a look at this

Comment: @seek Added another alternative (easier than Weiler algo)

Comment: hi @TamasIonut *"Triangulate your polygons (harder part)"* indeed since this is in the context of a 3D graphics situation, you have for free a triangulation of the shape.  Indeed, note that getting the "what happens to be the outside polygon as a human would see it" is tedious and problematic. A mesh is just literally a **triangle list**, and does not even know if it is (say) connected smoothly, far less whether it has an overall meaning such as an outside edge etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow yes I'm here. I'm left this problem to wait a while but I will came back to this. This will be harder than I think but must be done also :)

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow Yes of course your answer will be very helpful for me. Thank  you!