# Unity3d: How to calculate the surface area of different colors in a colored mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have created a mesh in run-time with a special shared. The shared has the following property:
1. When it is colored for the first time the color is blue
2. When it is colored for the second time the color is yellow
3. When it is colored for the third time the color is red
4. When it is colored for the fourth or more the color becomes green

Here's an example of the colored region:

[image]

In the above image the green region has many layer of mashes. I cannot calculate the area by summing up the triangles in mesh because there are many overlaps.

**EDIT!** I am updating question with more information
The mesh is generated using the following code (it's not the whole code by it is enough to give a general idea of how the mesh is generated)

```
for (int i = start; i<colorUntil; i++)
{
    parent.position = currentPosition;
    Vector3 relativePos = points[i + 1] - points[i];
    if (relativePos.magnitude > 0.5)
    {
        parent.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
    }

    currentPosition = points[i];
    Vector3 offset = parent.right * width / 2f;
    vertices.Add(currentPosition - offset);
    vertices.Add(currentPosition + offset);

    uvs.Add(new Vector2(0, 1));
    uvs.Add(new Vector2(1, 1));

    if (vertices.Count< 4)
    {
        return;
    }

    int c = vertices.Count;
    triangles.Add(c - 1);
    triangles.Add(c - 2);
    triangles.Add(c - 3);
    triangles.Add(c - 3);
    triangles.Add(c - 2);
    triangles.Add(c - 4);

    Vector3[] v = new Vector3[c];
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[c];
    int[] t = new int[triangles.Count];
    vertices.CopyTo(v, 0);
    uvs.CopyTo(uv, 0);
    triangles.CopyTo(t, 0);

    mesh.vertices = v;
    mesh.triangles = t;
    mesh.uv = uv;
}
```

Now I have to calculate the area of each color. Given the mesh above is it possible to calculate area of each color? Any suggestion would be welcome.

**EDIT 2!**
Apparently, there's no way to calculate the colored area using mash information (at least according to my research). How I am looking for a creative way to achieve what I want. I would welcome and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: could you add the code you use for coloring them? In general: run through the [`MeshFilter.mesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshFilter-mesh.html) -> [`Mesh.trinagles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html), calculate each [triangles area](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-area-triangle-without-right-angle.html) and sum the according areas up

Comment: If you have access to the mesh, then you have access to the triangles? Do you know the color of each trangle? If yes, just loop trhough them.

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for you comment. The problem is, the green section that you can see in the picture above has many layers of mashes. As I mentioned blue is one layer, yellow parts shows two mesh is overlapping, and green means four or more layers of meshes are overlapping. So calculating the total area of triangles will overstate the given area by many times.

Comment: @PierreBaret How about the when two mashes are overlapping?

Comment: oh ok .. you should update the question with that info because there it wasn't really clear that this is about overlapping meshes. And again: how is the image in your question generated? What is responsible for coloring the mesh in the first place?

Comment: @derHugo I updated the question as you suggested. The color is generated by a Shader which display different color for each overlap.

Comment: Did you also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942045/how-to-calculate-overall-area-of-multipy-meshes-that-overlap-itself)? Have you tried any of the things we mentioned before yet?

Comment: @derHugo, yes, as i mentioned triangle area summation doesn't give me the are of the region. I saw that link today and apparently there's no way to calculate the surface area let alone the area of different colors.

Comment: Can you explain why triangles area summation doesn't work? If meshes are overlapping, they have colored area anyway. If you only want the outer surface, than compute the outer surface and then sum the triangles. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you need an approximate result or an accurate result?

Comment: IMHO, an accurate result is almost impossible due to the areas are irregular, if an aproximate result is ok, you can render this scene into a large texture then count the green pixels.

Comment: If the colors are stored in a single texture, you could do it like this. Sample every triangle, get the UV coordinate for every sample, check the texture at that coordinate and take the color. Count the hits for every color and multiply it with the sampling surface If you sample in a grid, make the grid fine enough and take the cell area as sampling surface.

Comment: @shingo, approximate result should be fine since it is large area. Actually, that's what I did for my presentation (I screenshot the scene and placed it on a white background then calculated the pixels) but I didn't know it can be done internally in Unity. Can you please explain a little more so that I could implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script to take screenshot then count the green pixels.

Put the script on the render camera, set `m_TakeScreenshot` to true, it'll work in the current frame.

```cs
public class ScreenshotCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool m_TakeScreenshot;
    public Texture2D m_OutputTexture;

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        if (m_TakeScreenshot)
        {
            m_TakeScreenshot = false;

            //Take screenshot
            if (m_OutputTexture == null)
                m_OutputTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
            m_OutputTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
            m_OutputTexture.Apply();

            //Get all pixels, count green pixels
            var pixels = m_OutputTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, m_OutputTexture.width, m_OutputTexture.height);
            int greenPixels = 0, otherPixels = 0;
            foreach (var color in pixels)
            {
                //green
                if (color.g > 0.8f && color.r < 0.1f && color.b < 0.1f)
                    greenPixels++;
                //not black
                else if (color.r > 0.1f || color.g > 0.1f || color.b > 0.1f)
                    otherPixels++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take only set of green vertices, compute its Delaunay triangulation and then find its area. Or, to get more precise result - compute outline of concave hull instead of Delaunay, and then use [this pretty formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html) for area of arbitrary polygon.